# How can I dynamically put text in my navigation in my layout page

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I use bootstrap along with it, and in the navigation bar I have a link to a 'jobs' page.

Along with the 'jobs' text I put in a bootstrap badge. The idea is to fill this badge with the number that there are open jobs off.

I can calculate this in a controller or class by iterating through the jobs list and checking for a boolean value, but I don't know how I can put this value then in the HTML of the layout page.

For example, here is the code:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Jobs")"> Jobs <span class="badge">5</span> </a></li>
```

Here the '5' is the part that I want to insert dynamically. I just don't know from where/ how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a child action:

```
public class FooController
{
    ...

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult JobsBadge()
    {
        // retrieve number of jobs
        return PartialView("_JobsBadge", jobsCount);
    }
}
```

**Views/Foo/_JobsBadge.cshtml**

```
@model int
<span class="badge">@Model</span>
```

**Layout**

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Jobs")"> Jobs @Html.Action("JobsBadge", "Foo")</a></li>
```

*`FooController` can be whatever controller you like. Just put the action wherever it makes the most sense.*

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate just like this

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Jobs")"> Jobs <span class="badge">@Number</span> </a></li>
```

Comment: I don't understand where the number would come from then. In what controller or class should I calculate it then?

Comment: Create VAR Number, @{ var number = '5'; } where ever you want in controller on view and just pass it

Comment: But the layout page is used by most of my pages. Does that mean I need to put this in each controller then? Or will it remember that if I do it once in the home controller?

Comment: This answer only works if the job count is static, which I think it's safe to presume, it's not.

Comment: This is just example, i didint count that number!! The question is not about to count that number only for diplay